# ls | grep vim shows nothing (xorg same)

Tags: freebsd

I've installed FreeBSD 8
mounted the cdrom
went to cdrom/packages/All

```
cd /cdrom/packages/All
ls | grep vim
```

and nothing appears
same if I do

```
ls | grep xorg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, if you have the CDROM image, it has only the OS.  If you have the DVD, it has the base OS and pre-compiled packages.

Comment: There are multiple CD images: boot to installer only, base OS plus basic packages, live CD. There's also a DVD image with all the aforementioned, and a thumb-drive image.

Answer (score 1):

On my FreeBSD .iso the /packages/All contains bzip compressed tar files.

```
cd /media/cdrom/packages/All

ls

bn-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz  mn-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
da-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz  nl-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
de-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz  pl-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
el-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz  pt-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
en-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz  ru-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
es-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz  sr-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
fr-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz  tr-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
hu-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz  zh_cn-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
it-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz  zh_tw-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
ja-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
```

These are bzip2 compressed tar files. On the CD the `en-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz` just contains documetation.